# Getter method in a Enum class in Java

Tags: java, enums

How is the method `getAbbreviation()` in an Enum class implemented?
The following code is from the book Core Java I.

```
public class EnumTest {  

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a size: (SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, EXTRA_LARGE) ");
      String input = in.next().toUpperCase();
      Size size = Enum.valueOf(Size.class, input);
      System.out.println("size=" + size);
      System.out.println("abbreviation=" + size.getAbbreviation());
      if (size == Size.EXTRA_LARGE) {
         System.out.println("Good job--you paid attention to the _.");
      }    
   }
}
```

```
enum Size {
   SMALL("S"), MEDIUM("M"), LARGE("L"), EXTRA_LARGE("XL");

   private Size(String abbreviation) { 
      this.abbreviation = abbreviation; 
   }

   public String getAbbreviation() {
      return abbreviation; 
   }

   private String abbreviation;
}
```

The program execution picture is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKuqQ.png).

My question is: why it can output `abbreviation=S`, how is it implemented internally?

Comment: I don't see what's confusing here. You're asking how the `getAbbreviation()` method is implemented, but the implementation is literally in the code you posted.

Comment: [From the Oracle Enum tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) - "_Each enum constant is declared with values for the [SIC] its parameters. These values are passed to the constructor when the constant is created._"

Comment: You might be missing a syntax fact: `SMALL("S")` is an invocation of the enum constructor `Size(String abbreviation)` which then assigns the argument value of the parameter `abbreviation` to the field `abbreviation` via the assignment expression `this.abbreviation = abbreviation`. As a side-note, the abbreviation field of the enum should be final.

Comment: Thanks all very  much！I've got it. I don't realize it , the invocation of the enum constructor first. Actually,I had a guess that the Enum class might have handled it during construction at that time.Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It is an invocation of the enum constructor is an invocation of the enum constructor Size(String abbreviation).
Actually,the constructor of Enum class is private , programmer can not use it.So the provided code offered in the book

`SMALL("S"), MEDIUM("M"), LARGE("L"), EXTRA_LARGE("XL");`

is functionally the same to :

```
class Size{
private String abbreviation;
private Size(String abbreviation){this.abbreviation=abbreviation;}
public String getAbbreviation(){return abbreviation;}
public static Size SMALL = new Size("S");
public static Size MEDIUM = new Size("M");
public static Size LARGE = new Size("L");
public static Size EXTRA_LARGE = new Size("XL");
```

}

although i haven't found the source code of this implemention process,but I think it goes something like this.